# Check if an array is in the key of another array in PHP

Tags: php

I've an array like `$ignore_post = array("foo", "bar");` and I need to check if `foo` or `bar` is a key for `$_POST` (if `$_POST["foo"]` or `$_POST["bar"]` exists).

How I can do that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you familiar with a thing called "loop"?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: yes but I wanted to know if it was a way of doing without a loop :-)

Comment: there is **noway** to deal with arrays without loops. EVEN if you don't see it, a loop is always involved. go figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP function [`array_key_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
<?php
foreach($ignore_post as $key)
{
    if(array_key_exists($key,$_POST))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
?>
```

Alternatively you can replace `array_key_exists($key,$_POST)` with `isset($_POST[$key])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
<?php foreach ($ignore_post as $value){
if(!empty($_POST[$value])){
   echo 'It exists';
} else {
   echo 'It does not exist or is empty'
}
}?>

<?php foreach ($ignore_post as $value){
if(isset($_POST[$value])){
   echo 'It exists but might be empty';
} else {
   echo 'It does not exist'
}
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using array_key_exists php function.

For reference, visit [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)